# How to communicate with private EC2 instance from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Lets say we have a ec2 instance that running in the private subnet. No Public IP associated with this instance. There is a running application (server with endpoint) inside this instance.

Problem is I need to access this application endpoint through a Lambda function. If that instance had a public IP we could directly make a call to the instance but this instance is a private instance.

Is there any way to communicate with that private EC2 instance through a Lambda function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place a Lambda function inside of the VPC and configure the security groups to allow traffic from the Lambda function.

AWS Docs: [Configuring a Lambda function to access resources in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html)

Comment: hi @Maurice, I created lambda role as mentioned. Can you please explain how to invoke instance endpoint from the lambda? Do I need to curl or something? what is the URL of the endpoint?

Comment: That depends on the endpoint, you need to make a call to the private IP of the instance on the port your application server is running, e.g. `http://10.0.0.15:8080/`

Comment: Hey thanks Maurice. Its working. Appreciate your help.